# clojure newbie, nothing is printed to console in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

I created `test.clj`

I have this code in it:

```
(ns clojure.examples.hello
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [greetee]
  (println (str "Hello " greetee "!")))
```

result:

> /home/bin/java /tmp/testclj/src/test.clj
>
> (**where are my printings? shouldn't they appear here? nothing is printed here**)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

but i get nothing printed out when i run it shouldn't it be printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you run your code?

First, you need to compile it:

```
(compile 'clojure.examples.hello)
```

And then:

```
java -cp ./classes:clojure.jar clojure.examples.hello Jas
```

*Of course, path depends on your project structure.*

I would say, it is much more easier if you installed IntelliJ Leiningen plugin and trying to run your code with Leiningen.

With Leiningen, you can do:

```
; run the -main function of a namespace
lein run -m my.namespace
```

And it is always a good idea, not to rely on IDEs to run and build your projects.

Comment: "And it is always a good idea, not to rely on IDEs to run and build your projects." - why? shouldn't IDE's give you a quick way to build and run?

Comment: @vikingsteve Supposed, yes. But not all of your team (or online contributors) is going to use IntelliJ, Eclipse, Visual Studio, Xcode (put other name here). Otherwise, you will have the syndrome: "But it works on machine". Add to that, by using independent build tools, your project becomes ContinuousDelivery and ContinuousIntegration friendly.

Comment: Okay, I now understand your point that IDE's should not be the *only* way to build and run projects. But from a convenience perspective they should definitely be well integrated with your language via plugins - alt-tabbing the whole time to do builds is ineffective and tedious.

Comment: right, so use a build tool, and an IDE that integrates with that tool - all of the Clojure IDEs worth the name have lein integration

Answer (score 2):

Old question I know, but in case someone else runs into this: the default configuration that IntelliJ creates did not print anything on my computer either. Instead, do the following:

- go to `Edit Configuration`
- change `Run Clojure script` to `Run -main from Clojure namespace` and fill in your namespace (for example, `hello.world`)
- `Run with Leiningen` should have been activated automatically

If you run this config instead of the default (and have Leiningen installed, naturally), you should get logs printed to console.

Comment: Worst user experience ever. Thanks for posting this.